# Rewriting log of a sum

Tags: summation, logarithms

Suppose we have a vector

$$X=[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n],\quad x_i\in \mathbb{R} \text{ for } i=1,2,\ldots,n $$

Now if we have a formula
$$f_X(x)=\log\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i\right)$$
Is it possible to rewrite $f$ in any way, such that one can take the logarithm directly to the $x_i's$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of the relation $\sum_{i} \log x_{i}=\log \prod_{i} x_{i}$.

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is the log of a sum of numbers. Unfortunately, there is no "simple" formula for rewriting this. Read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974793/to-compute-logab) for an example of what you can do to $log(a+b)$ for starters.

Comment: Thank you, I wasnt able to find that thread by searching myself.